How to remove icon in alert dialog?
How can I remove icon?
I want to show only title, description and button.
This is how the dialog is presented.

Button {
    store.send(.sendRequestButtonTapped)
    showingAlert = true
} label: {
    Text(TR("Send request"))
        .font(MeditUIKitFontFamily.NotoSans.regular.swiftUIFont(size: 14))
}
.buttonStyle(GhostedButtonStyle(
    ButtonProperties(
        size: .small,
        shape: .roundedRectangle,
        background: .bTransparent,
        foreground: MeditUIKitAsset.lightPrimaryP600.swiftUIColor
    )
))
.alert(isPresented: $showingAlert) {
    Alert(
        title: Text(TR("Request sent")),
        message: Text(TR("You will be notified once the lab approves your request.")),
        dismissButton: .default(Text("Ok"), action: {
            showingAlert = false
        })
    )
}


I don't think this is possible. You can reinvent an alert with a sheet though.

You can set the icon of the alert to a transparent image using dialogIcon:
.dialogIcon(Image(size: .init(width: 10, height: 10)) { _ in })

which is basically the same hack as this. It will still leave the space where the icon should have been, blank.
As this comment says, the icon is an integral part of an alert on macOS. You should embrace this design, or else design your own alert.
You can make your alert-like thing using a sheet.
.sheet(isPresented: $showingAlert) {
    VStack(spacing: 20) {
        Text("Request Sent")
            .font(.headline)
        Text("You will be notified once the lab approves your request.")
            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
            .font(.caption)
        Button {
            showingAlert = false
        } label: {
            Text("Ok")
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .padding(.vertical, 5)
        }
        .keyboardShortcut(.defaultAction)
        .buttonStyle(.bordered)
    }
    .padding()
    .frame(width: 200)
    .interactiveDismissDisabled()
}

